# NSLayoutAttribute extension to add a case

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I'm trying to create an extension for `NSLayoutAttribute` so I can use `NSLayoutAttribute.bot` instead of `NSLayoutAttribute.bottom`.

I've tried to use a typealias, but since `.bottom` is not a type it doesn't seem to be working. Extending `NSLayoutAttribute` and adding a case `bot` doesn't seem like it should be the way as well.

So instead I tried:

```
extension NSLayoutAttribute {
    var bot: NSLayoutAttribute { return NSLayoutAttribute.bottom }
}
```

> Instance member 'bot' cannot be used on type 'NSLayoutAttribute'

It's something which has been bothering me for a while and was just wondering if it's possible to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **static** variable to be able to access it:

```
extension NSLayoutAttribute {
    static var bot: NSLayoutAttribute {
        get {
            return NSLayoutAttribute.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: of course, havent been programming for over half a year and seems like I have to start from scratch :(. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! please accept the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Have to wait a few more minutes to do that. Cheers!

Comment: Correct answer. However for readability you should definitely stick to bottom ;)

Comment: Yes, I've been doing that but since the beginning when I started with Swift, it has been itching me. I was just wondering if it's possible. I probably will use this so it won't annoy me any further! :)